# Token based Custom authentication WSo2

Tags: wso2

I am currently working on a product based on WSO2  and need to customized the Authentication. Actually We have Users, who has hyphen (-) in the User Id which has to be authenticated through WSO2 BPS server while WSO2 doesn't allow them because of hyphen(-). These User names are created from outside system so we do not have any control over naming convention but We want to login with those User names.

So we want to pass only User ID and it should return a session id so that we can intiatie Human Task services and invoke WSO2 services.

I have got a sample Custom Authenticator :
http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.in/2011/08/carbon-authentication-framework.html

We archive above project and place in "repository\components\dropins".This is working fine But this is not a token based authentication.so no use foe us.

Could you please provide us any sample for Token based Custom Authentication which should be pluggable to WSo2 carbon server 4.X.X.

Comment: Hi WSO2 experts, please help me out . I have been waiting for 24 hours. I expect by helping each other only we can spread WSO2 more effectively.